# MySQL SELECT query with OR and Brackets not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

Hi I have a MySQL Select query as follow.

```
SELECT * 
FROM request
WHERE user_id=$user_id 
   OR vendor=$user_id
   OR (status='' AND services IN ( $service_arr )) 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

But this query is not working as expected. My OR condition is neglected and this query is getting data only when conditions under brackets are true.
Meaning its getting only those rows where column name `services` has one of the items present in `$service_arr`.

Thanks

Comment: There is no error or something illogical in your request !
Try to make a var_dump(your_query) or echo ; to see what you get in mysql directly

Comment: Your query looks fine. Can you edit your question with some sample data that shows the problem?

Comment: I am not sure why your question has been upvoted.  It is Unclear and Off-topic because we don't know why your code is not working as desired.

Comment: @Nick this is a "Why isn't my code working" question.

Comment: @mickmackusa absolutely hence my comment to request some more detail on how it is not working. As you say it can't be answered without it.

Comment: I'm with you.  You've been kind @Nick.  After 50 minutes, time to close.

Comment: @mickmackusa it could still be lunchtime! but you're right... it's bad form to post and leave...

Comment: I'm happy to reopen if it is ever edited to be a good/unique question.

Answer (score 0):

This example most probably help you

```
SELECT customer_id,first_name, last_name 
FROM customers 
WHERE (last_name = 'atiq')
   OR (last_name = 'hamza' AND state = 'attock')
   OR (last_name = 'usman' AND status = 'Active' AND state = 'islamabad');
```

Comment: Please never post code-only answers on Stackoverflow.  They are low-value because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating a SQL fiddle with above table definition, loaded with sample data and tested above SQL. it seems to work fine.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/282e9f/2

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `request` (
  `user_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vendor` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `services` varchar(200) NOT NULL
 
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `request` (`user_id`, `vendor`, `status`, `services`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', 'cut','fit'),
   ('2', '1', 'cut','fit'), ('3', '3', '','pick'),
    ('4', '5', 'next','sample');
```

```
SELECT * 
FROM request
WHERE user_id=1
   OR vendor=1
   OR (status='' AND services IN ('pick'));
```

## Result set

```
user_id vendor  status  services
1        1       cut         fit
2        1       cut         fit
3        3                   pick
```

I could not find anything wrong with your SQL, can you share a sample with the data ?